# Can we use operator in function?

Tags: sql-server

Why using operator is not working for me in the function?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Sales.fn_FilteredExtension','IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION Sales.fn_FilteredExtension;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION Sales.fn_FilteredExtension
(
    @lowqty smallint,
    @highqty smallint
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT unitprice,qty
           FROM Sales.OrderDetails where (qty <= @highqty) AND (qty >= @lowqty)
);
GO
```

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.fn_FilteredExtension(20,15)
```

I get blank results but when I use

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Sales.fn_FilteredExtension','IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION Sales.fn_FilteredExtension;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION Sales.fn_FilteredExtension
(
    @lowqty smallint,
    @highqty smallint
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT unitprice,qty
           FROM Sales.OrderDetails where qty BETWEEN @highqty AND @lowqty
);
GO
```

I get the output. What's the difference ?

Comment: Look again at your use of `@highqty` and `@lowqty` and whether they're correct in either your parameter passing or your use of `between`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting your parameters mixed up and then reversed
Your BETWEEN statement takes the lowest value as the first parameter and the higher value as the second parameter and so it shouldnt work if @lowqty actually receives the smallest value

Change "FROM Sales.OrderDetails where qty BETWEEN @highqty AND @lowqty"

To     "FROM Sales.OrderDetails where qty BETWEEN @lowqty AND @highqty"

and then make sure @lowqty is actually the smallest value passed

Easy mix up given what the word BETWEEN means in common usage and then wrong values coming in

Comment: Aha.. that's what I missed on. thanks for the explanation. 
so I need to make sure my parameters are passed in the order, I define in the function.
I put a higher value in lowqty and low in highqty but the statement BETWEEN did its job but when I used operator there can't be a value which is greater than 19 AND less than 16 and thus a blank result... thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass correct arguments:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.fn_FilteredExtension(20,15)
<=>
SELECT * FROM Sales.fn_FilteredExtension(15,20)
```